# Completely ignore new lines in regex

Tags: regex, cpanel

I know the `/s` modifier in regex, but it doesn't work with my specific case.

For example I'm trying to create a spam filter that matches urls with various domains like this

> https://www.theonlineleaflets.com/u=/544hfb34s21jv335hs/u
>
> Regex: `https:\/\/www\..+?\/u\/\w{18}\/u`

The problem is that the spammers insert newlines and `=` symbols randomly like such:

```
<area  coords=3D"0,0,1000,1000" href=3D"https://www.theonlineleaflets.com/u=
/544hfb34s21jv335hs/u"/>
```

OR:

```
<area  coords=3D"0,0,1000,1000" href=3D"https://www.netprofessionalbitcoin.=
com/u/565i71cag5hd3kdh3mds/u"/>
```

OR:

```
<area  coords=3D"0,0,1000,1000" href=3D"https://www.theonlineleaflets.com/=
u/544hfb34s21jv335hs/u"/>
```

I'm pretty much sure new lines cannot be ignored, but I'm asking in case I'm wrong, or someone knows a better regex tu flag these spammers that would be precise enough.

**NOTE**: This is for cPanel, so I suppose it's standard PERL format and I don't think it supports modifiers like `/s` anyways.

**UPDATE**: It seems like the new line is always following the `=` sign, however this sign can be anywhere in the url.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this regex that takes into account potential newlines.

```
https:\/\/www\..+?\/=?(?:\s*?)?u(?:\s*?)?=?(?:\s*?)?\/.*?u
```

Basically, I use `(?:\s*?)?` which is an optional, non-capturing, lazy match of any number of whitespace characters, including newlines. If you want to restrict it to just newlines, use `\n` instead. [Here's](https://regex101.com/r/hx7Hri/1) a demo.

Comment: Thanks friend, I updated my question, as I got some new details and your regex doesn't work with the second example (I changed it), because the `=` sign can be anywhere in the link

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your regex to support '`=`' and `White Space` (incl. `Newlines`).

This the regex:

```
https:\/\/www\..+?\/[u=\s]+\/[\w=\s]+\/[u=\s]+
```

What I have changed is to use character classes instead of literal matches. That way the '=' and Newlines are effectively ignored and it will match all your examples.

The only 'problem' is that I removed the '`{18}`' quantifier (since those bad characters take up room).

**Edit** as per the comment:

```
https:\/\/www\.[\s\S]+?\/[u=\s]+\/[\w=\s]+\/[u=\s]+
```

I have changed a dot '`.`' to the character class '`[\s\S]`'. Now there can be `Newlines` in the url as well.

About the 18 quantifier: There's 20 chars in your second example, so it won't match if you limit that string.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think you might be close to the solution (although I'm a bit concerned for a broad match without the 18 characters), however the `=` sign can be anywhere in the link, I updated my question and replaced example 2 to illustrate :)